# How do I perform healthcheck of a grpc service using traefik?

Tags: grpc, traefik, health-monitoring, health-check

I am using Traefik with etcd as backend. I don't know how do I perform the health check for the grpc service. If it was a normal webservice I think the path option of healthcheck works fine, but how do I do it when I have a grpc service.